# JavaScript Date don't get Timezone in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I try to store some Date on mongo Collections.
When I do `let date = new Date(); MaCol.insert({'date': date});`, I can see on my mongo collection that the date is stored with the correct timezone
(something like : 2017-05-22 12:42:28.441Z).
But if I use a value on constructor of Date like `let date = new Date('03/03/2000)` i lose the time zone : 2000-03-03 00:00:00.000Z
How to correct that ?

Thanks.

Comment: moment.js is best for all things dates in javascript.  Check it out: https://momentjs.com/docs/ - Personally, I'd store all dates as a Unix timestamp, and then manipulate to the relevant format on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You should use moment.js to make this a breeze. They support a ton of options. In your case, using moment js, the below should work:

```
moment('03/03/2000').format();
>> "2000-03-03T00:00:00+05:30"
```

You can test other options by just visiting the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) page, opening up the dev console and directly typing in the above (or other format commands) to see if it gets you what you neeed.